# Drawing an arc in phaser and apply tween to reduce its length within 5 second

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

Hey I want to draw a circle with phaser v2.3.0 and reduce it uniformly by applying tween on it.
It should look like [this](https://codepen.io/agrimsrud/pen/EmCoa). But starting from a full circle perimeter(kind of hollow disk with some thickness at the perimeter) and reduce its perimeter uniformly withing 5 second.
You can take help with [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/lewster32/0yvemxnw/) 
As I am new to phaser so I am able to understand it or if you can give me simple example or solution, it would be better.
`Thanks in advance`

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer

```
var GameState = {
   update: function () {
        this.graphics.clear();
        this.graphics.lineStyle(6, 0xffffff);
        this.graphics.arc(40, 90, 20, 0, 
                   game.math.degToRad(this.angle.max), true, 128);
        this.graphics.endFill();
   }
   create: function () {
        this.graphics = game.add.graphics(0, 0);
        this.world.bringToTop(this.graphics)
        this.angle = { min: 0, max: 0 };
        this.roundArcTween = this.add.tween(this.angle).to({ max: 360 }, 5000);
   }

}
```